# Should we be less strict with high view count questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation

Now that we have SEDE, I created a query with high viewcount questions ( linked to JavaScript ). My assumption is that traffic to these questions is Google generated.

Should a question like this : [Faster and cleaner way to parse Parameters from URL in javascript/jQuery?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/9574/14625)

really be closed since this could be the first exposure to CR for a visitor? I understand the question does not follow the rules, but mayhaps we can grant an exception ? I just dont want CR to look like Wikipedia or SO.

Comment: The question you've linked to has almost 13,500 views. It generated 11 answer upvotes and 3 question upvotes - 125 reputation. Something's not adding up.

Comment: Well, lol.upvote helped closing it ;)

Comment: I know a monkey that helped closing it too :)

Comment: don't forget the Zombie

Comment: Rule of thumb: High view count or many votes does not make a question on-topic, better or more fitting for this site. The same problem was on SO, the most upvoted questions were off-topic ones...they were closed, deleted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think these questions (off-topic, old, highly viewed) ought to be tracked and closed. They date back from an age of darkness, when the site's scope wasn't as clear-cut as it is today.

If they're valuable content with some upvoted answers, then perhaps we should put a historical lock on them. I have flagged the question you've mentioned as such.

As a beta site, we cannot afford to "be less strict" on *anything* that can affect the site's scope.

Answer (score 6):

I know that some questions that are migrated a long time ago, don't retain the migrated mark for all eternity, I have noticed this on other sites as well.

taking that into consideration, those votes and answers may have come from StackOverflow.

---

another point to address is that this person posted someone else's code here.

**They could be Violating Licensing just by posting it here.**

this could be a legal issue, therefore we cannot afford to be less strict on this high view question.

if this question didn't have someone else's code, it could be locked with a note that says this isn't what we normally do here but it brings people to our wonderful site and tells them what we do.

Comment: Source : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727081/function-to-retrieve-url-variables-using-javascript-and-jquery

Comment: it still isn't OP's code. if he had linked to the question it would be clear who's code it was, and that it was posted under license.  but the bottom line is, it's not their code and we don't want others doing it.

Answer (score 3):

From the perspective of someone who only occasionally pops into Code Review but is very active on CodeGolf: I think that in general a stack should be *more* strict, not less, with high-profile questions, because those questions have a disproportionate influence on what people perceive as the scope and purpose of the site.